# I didn't get the file name i,e zip file while using the file input method,o/p file type is file and i want zip file with the same name

Tags: java

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session=request.getSession();

    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String examId=request.getParameter("source");
    session.setAttribute("dur",examId);
    String fileName = examId+".zip";
    List<String> filesListInDir = new ArrayList<String>();
    File dir = new File("C:/Temp/Answers");     // Our source file 
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    int flag=0;
    for(File file : files){
        if(file.isFile()){      
            response.setContentType("APPLICATION/zip");
            String disHeader = "zip";
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", disHeader);
            filesListInDir.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            if(file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)){
                flag = 1;
                session.setAttribute("fileName", file.getName());
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());  
                int i;   
                while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
                out.write(i);   
                }   
                fileInputStream.close();   
                out.close();   
                }  
        }
        if(flag == 0){
            System.out.println("file not match");
            out.print("Answer is not uploaded");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add some text to your question in order to clarify what you're asking. 
Beware that your current first line should be formatted with at least 4 spaces before in order to let it show as code.
TRhe title too should be made clearer

Comment: Actually i design this code to download a zip file from a particular location,but when i download it give me output as a file instead of zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code.

1- let's assume what you read are already zip files.
In this case you should change the `response.setContentType` and the `response.setHeader` parts as follows

```
    response.setContentType("application/zip"); 
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + fileName );
```

2- You loop in a folder and try to send the response header (contentType and content Disposition) once for each file in the folder. This should generate an "Header Already Sent" Exception from server, after the first file has been sent. So you should make something like this

```
int flag=0;
for(File file : files){
    if(file.isFile()){      
        filesListInDir.add(file.getAbsolutePath()); // what is the utility of this ??
        if(file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)){
            flag = 1;
            response.setContentType("application/zip"); 
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=" + fileName );

            session.setAttribute("fileName", file.getName());
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());  
            int i;   
            while ((i=fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {  
               out.write(i);   
            }//closes while   
            fileInputStream.close();   
            out.close();   
            return; //you finished if you sent the file
         }  // closes if(file.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName))
    } // closes if(file.isFile())

}// closes for

//following block moved after the for so it prints at most once
if(flag == 0){
    System.out.println("file not match");
    out.print("Answer is not uploaded");
}
```